# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not working with Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, geolocation

I have just started to find that navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition does not work with Firefox when I decline to reveal my location. I.e. it does not return with the error as it did before. It works fine on Safari and Chrome but not Firefox 33.1

I can see this problem when running the w3schools example code (http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error) which is as follows:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This works on Firefox if I allow access to my position. If I deny access neither the showPosition or showError functions get called. Nothing happens. I have tried this with both Mac and PC Firefox and get the same problem. Works fine with Safari and Chrome though.

Comment: works on FF 30.0, downloading latest

Comment: also works on FF 34.0 - maybe an issue with 33.1? What is the error you are seeing? The object passed to showError is `PositionError { code: 1, message: "User denied geolocation prompt" }` for me.

Comment: I am not seeing an error at all it is as if the function does not return

Comment: My problem is that neither the showPosition nor the showError functions get called if I deny access.

Answer (score 0):

I have just discovered this is a feature of Firefox, or bug as I would prefer to call it. It is detailed here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=675533